# Pass in a string for an object

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm making a method that gets info from my my MySQL database, this is what my MySQL tables look like.

```sql
create table Person(
  personId int primary key not null auto_increment,
  firstname varchar(255) not null,
  lastname varchar(255) not null,
  type varchar(1) not null,
  username varchar(255) not null,
  password varchar(255) not null
);
```

```sql
create table Account(
  accountId int primary key not null auto_increment,
  accountNumber int not null,
  currentBalance double not null,
  type varchar(1) not null,
  personId int not null,
  foreign key(personId) references Person(personId)
);
```

```java
rs = ps.executeQuery();
int i = 0;
while (rs.next()) {
    if (rs.getString("type").equals("C")) { 
        String firstName = rs.getString("firstName");
        int accountNumber = rs.getInt("accountNumber");
        double currentBalance = rs.getDouble("currentBalance");
        CheckingAccount acc = new CheckingAccount(firstName, accountNumber,currentBalance);
        accounts.add(i,acc);
        i++;
    }
    if (rs.getString("type").equals("S")) {
        String firstName = rs.getString("firstName");
        int accountNumber = rs.getInt("accountNumber");
        double currentBalance = rs.getDouble("currentBalance");
        SavingAccount acc = new SavingAccount(firstName, accountNumber,currentBalance);
        accounts.add(i,acc);
        i++;
    }
    if (rs.getString("type").equals("G")) {
        String firstName = rs.getString("firstName");
        int accountNumber = rs.getInt("accountNumber");
        double currentBalance = rs.getDouble("currentBalance");
        GoldSavingAccount acc = new GoldSavingAccount(firstName, accountNumber,currentBalance);
        accounts.add(i,acc);
        i++;
    }
    if (rs.getString("type").equals("P")) {
        String firstName = rs.getString("firstName");
        int accountNumber = rs.getInt("accountNumber");
        double currentBalance = rs.getDouble("currentBalance");
        PlatinumSavingAccount acc = new PlatinumSavingAccount(firstName,accountNumber,currentBalance);
        accounts.add(i,acc);
        i++;
    }

}

rs.close();
return accounts;
```

The issue is when I try making a new CheckingAccount, I have to put in a person for my first field. My checkingAccount constructor looks like this

```java
public class CheckingAccount extends Account {
    
    public CheckingAccount(Person p, int i, double d) {
        super(p,i, d);
    }
```

```java
public abstract class Account {
    
    private Person accountHolder;
    private int accountId;
    private int accountNumber;
    private double currentBalance;
    private String type;
    
    public Account() {}
    
    public Account(Person accountHolder, int accountNumber, double currentBalance) {
        this.accountHolder = accountHolder;
        this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
        this.currentBalance = currentBalance;
    }
```

And this is what it's extended out to, I tried constructor overloading and It didn't work, I cant make new instance of a person because I'm only trying to get the account info from my database. How would I go about tackling this? I tried passing in Person accountHolder and instead of firstName I put accountHolder, but when running in my main file it only prints the name of one person.

Comment: Please [edit] the post and format the code properly.

Comment: MySQL Or SQL Server? Please correct your tags.